# Cannot align divs with % widths or heights properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I am having problems aligning elements on my page properly.  I have a live example here..http://newbapps.com/8ball/

The div 'answer' should be overlayed over the triangle in the img 'ball'.  The problem is, I want this too look properly centered even with different window sizes.  If I was using pixel width/height values for my image and div, it would be easier to accomplish, but since I am using percentages my div 'answer' is not being properly centered within 'ball'.  Please help :(

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #ball {
            width: auto;
            height: 50%;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #answer {
            width: 5%;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 6%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        textarea {
            width: 600px;
            height: 100px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        button {
            width: 600px;
            height: 50px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 4.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
<p id="answer">Yes.</p>
<img src="ball.png" id="ball">
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick="getAnswer()">Shake</button>
<script>
    function getAnswer() {
        var answers = ["It is certain.",
                        "It is decidedly so.",
                        "Without a doubt.",
                        "Yes definitely.",
                        "You may rely on it.",
                        "As I see it, yes.",
                        "Most likely.",
                        "Outlook good.",
                        "Yes.",
                        "Signs point to yes.",
                        "Reply hazy try again.",
                        "Ask again later.",
                        "Better not tell you now.",
                        "Cannot predict now.",
                        "Concentrate and ask again.",
                        "Don't count on it.",
                        "My reply is no.",
                        "My sources say no.",
                        "Outlook not so good.",
                        "Very doubtful."]
        var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = randomAnswer;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put both images (`#ball`) and the answer (`#answer`) in a container `div`, give it `position: relative;` and afterwards position the elements using `position: absolute;`.

Comment: I added a container, set its position to relative, and #ball and #answer to absolute, but am still having problems.

Comment: After playing around with it for awhile, I found that your suggestion actually was the answer.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.